# MYSQL LEFT JOIN 3 Tables (1st Table returning empty values)

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out why Table A is returning null value after I left join with Table B. It should be 3 tables but for now, i'm just getting the two tables to work.

```html
Table A
IUEID  DATE  MONTH  DATAA
4444   01    JAN    150
4444   02    JAN    98
4444   03    JAN    78
4444   04    JAN    55 

TABLE B
IUEID  DATE   MONTH  DATAB
4444   02     JAN    CORN
4444   03     JAN    GRAPES

SELECT *, TABLEB.DATAB
FROM TABLEA
LEFT JOIN TABLEB
ON TABLEB.IUEID = TABLEA.IUEID
AND TABLEB.DATE = TABLEA.DATE
GROUP BY TABLEA.DATE

OUTPUT:
IUEUD     DATE     DATAA      DATAB
(empty)  (empty)   150       (emtpy)
4444     02        98        CORN
4444     03        78        GRAPES
(empty)  (empty)   55        (empty)
```

Comment: is the query you posted and the output as it is when you are running it or did you modify it here when you posted the question? The output looks as if you are selecting the columns with empty data from the tableB

Comment: What's the group by ment to do?  Group by without aggregation generally makes no sense.  It may be hiding the rows you expect to see..  maybe you mean order by?  Also  instead of `*` use `tableA.*` or better spell out each column explicitly; the engine could be getting confused about which column to display since names are the same in both tables.  Provide a sqlfiddle.com or rextester.com working example showing the problem; but I bet the * or the group by is causing the issue. in mysql

Comment: You said, "I can't figure out why Table A is returning null value after I left join with Table B."  How do you know it's table A that's null?  Are you sure the engine is using A in the select and not b?  alias the `*` to `tableA.*`  mySQL can be quirky when you have tables with the same column name!  Other RDBMS would indicate an error as they wouldn't be able to resolve which table column you mean; mysql assumes they are equal and picks one. (much more complex than this but general gist)

Comment: Hi @xQbert I'll try this out too. Thanks! regarding your question, I assumed It's A or should I say NULL columns instead of entire table row since I can see that DATAA (150) from Table A. But IUEID and DATE are empty.

Comment: @isaace yes i just simulated it. Table A has date from Jan 01 to Jan 30 so as Table B. If i don't put Group by date it will display repeat date several times when running the result.

Comment: check the query from my answer using distinct instead of group by.

Comment: @localhost did my query work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify in your select from which table the query should pull from then is should work as expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.IUEUD, A.DATE, A.DATAA, B.DATAB
FROM TABLEA A
LEFT JOIN TABLEB B
   ON TABLEB.IUEID = TABLEA.IUEID
   AND TABLEB.DATE = TABLEA.DATE
```

Comment: Hi @isaace. I've tried but got the same result <pre> "SELECT  
 a.Date1,
 a.Date,
 a.Agent_ID,
 a.Agent_Name,
 a.Open,
 a.New,
 a.Decline,
 a.RFI_done_by_CO,
 a.RFI_done_by_Entity,
 b.FCA_made,
 b.Date1,
 b.Date,
 b.Agent_ID
 FROM `view_agent_co_performance` a
 LEFT JOIN `view_agent_case_closure` b
 ON b.Agent_ID = a.Agent_ID
 AND b.Date1 = a.Date1
 WHERE a.Agent_ID = 'IUE0003060'
 ORDER BY a.Date ASC"; </pre>

Answer (score 1):

This won't work for all records because not all records in table B have a date value that matches in table A so it has nothing to join onto. Therefore it shows the value as it is in table A and nulls the Table B columns. This is typical of the characteristics of a left join. If you want to show records where they only appear in both tables, you should use a inner join instead.

Lookup the use of different [joins](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/)  to see how they work to get a better understanding.

Comment: it should still work if the query is selecting those columns explicitly from tableA

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` will show you all the values from TABLEA and then will match then with the values in TABLEB. If there is no data related in TABLEB, it will show null.

Like Juakali92 suggested use just `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried Join and Inner Join, it completely removes the date that doesn't match on Table B...  while Left join displays all except that the IUE and DATE returns null

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for sharing your thoughts... I was able to solved the problem by adding..

```html
Used Join and Inner Join (It removes the result that doesn't match Table B) Left Join displays the result but IUEID and DATE are empty so I add the following IFNULL

SELECT a.IUEID, a.DATE, b.DATAB
IFNULL(a.IUEID,'0') as IUEIDa,
IFNULL(a.DATE,'0') as DATEa,
FROM TABLEA
LEFT JOIN TABLEB
ON TABLEB.IUEID = TABLEA.IUEID
AND TABLEB.DATE = TABLEA.DATE
ORDER BY TABLEA.DATE

Thanks for all your help.
```